# onclick on input File, fired only one time onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code.
When the "simulateClickBtn" is called, a system popup appears to choose a file.
When the file is choose we are going to the callback and the sendMessage function is done.
But it works only the first time. The others times, i never go in change callBack..

HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="hiddenInput" name="somename" size="chars">
```

JS :

```
this.simulateClickBtn = function simulateClickBtn() {
  localFileChoose = undefined ;

  $('#hiddenInput').click();

  $('#hiddenInput').off().on("change", function(evt){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      message : "SHOW_UPLOAD_TYPE_VIEW",
      fileName: evt.target.files[0].name,
    }, function(response) { });

    localFileChoose = evt.target.files[0];
  });
};
```

Comment: What are you doing to make the popup appear the second time? Inside the the `simulateClickBtn` function you are unbinding all events on the input before binding the change event, so if you are relying on an event on the input such as a click to open the popup again this will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you probably don't want to be binding the hidden click handler inside the simulate click handler. That will re-bind it every time you click which is unnecessary. Try something like this:

```
var chosenFile;

this.simulateClickBtn = function simulateClickBtn() {
  $('#hiddenInput').click();
};

$('#hiddenInput').on('change', function(evt) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    message : 'SHOW_UPLOAD_TYPE_VIEW',
    fileName: evt.target.files[0].name,
  }, function(response) { });

  chosenFile = evt.target.files[0];
});
```

Comment: try to declare chosenFile globally.